# The experience `devName` attribute is returning and invalid name for `File_Related_List__c` route

Tags: lightning-experience, devopscenter, experience

I've been getting a weird one lately (last month+) that's stopping me from deploying an experience/community.

Just what I've found in case someone else has seen this.

### Context

Salesforce has recently added a new `devName` attribute to the experience routes (i.e. `force-app/main/default/experiences/My_Experience_Name/routes/*.json`).

The route `devName` naming convention seems similar to the SObject naming convention.

Since that introduction I have been unable to deploy the community.

### Error

The error is as follows:

> My_Experience_Name of Type ExperienceBundle failed to deploy due to Because the e0a5ca39-5b40-4d74-997e-14b0fb9f26d6 route is a default template route, its devName can’t end with a __c suffix. Specify a valid devName and try again.

### Attempted Resolutions

#### Remove that attribute from the deployment

This throws:

> ERROR deploying ExperienceBundle experiences/My_Experience_Name: You seem to be missing the property devName in My_Experience_Name/routes/fileRelatedList.json with component ID: e0a5ca39-5b40-4d74-997e-14b0fb9f26d6

#### Remove the __c from the devName

This throws:

> ERROR deploying ExperienceBundle experiences/My_Experience_Name: The devName of an existing route can’t be changed. Revert the devName of the e0a5ca39-5b40-4d74-997e-14b0fb9f26d6 route back to its original value and try again.

### Some details

Site is a "Customer Account Portal" experience using the Jepson.

I've noticed that the "File Related List" route is returning as `File_Related_List__c` in my other work org. Unfortunately, it's not the sort of place where collaboration is possible :/ - and I have not seen any issues yet.

**`routes/fileRelatedList.json`**

```json
{
  "activeViewId" : "504f2d92-aa72-437a-9d8a-91f843ab39d7",
  "appPageId" : "9e5b12bf-f5a5-4c7e-84ef-514067ed5b8f",
  "configurationTags" : [ ],
  "devName" : "File_Related_List__c",
  "id" : "e0a5ca39-5b40-4d74-997e-14b0fb9f26d6",
  "label" : "File Related List",
  "routeType" : "relatedlist-069",
  "type" : "route",
  "urlPrefix" : "contentdocument"
}
```

### Workaround (kind of)

Deploy using API v58.0 rather than v59.0 (as `devName` is ignored prior to v59.0).

The assumption here is you have control of the API version - which in this project I think I don't without manual deployments.  Been playing with the DevOps centre - so now to find out whether the API version can be controlled :).

---

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you are facing has been identified as a [Known issue](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000xAUYo/experience-bundle-deployments-fail-due-to-devname-property) (#W-14394846) associated with the Winter'24 release. At the moment, there's no estimated time for the bug fix. However, I recommend subscribing to the known issue to receive updates once the fix becomes available.

Copying workaround from the known issue

> 1. Retrieve the bundle metadata using API version 58 and deploy to target org.
> 2. Reach out to Salesforce support if the above workaround did not help.

Comment: Cheers - I'll keep an eye on that and update this post

Comment: I was told the fix ETA was one month

Comment: I hope that is the case.  The known issue site says `Scheduled for Summer '24!! I look forward to a day where I can build stuff other than workarounds :D